# What is the difference among 3 methods when I want to upload data?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, nginx, python-requests, urllib

## My question

I am building a web application with Python3. I prepare a server with nginx and an application server with gunicorn. When I want to upload data from client computer to server computer, I found there are several ways to make it possbile. At least, following methods seems to be suitable for it.

- using urllib.request
- using requests
- using socket

However, I still do not understand what is the difference among these methods ?

I want to hear your comments and advise.

Answer (score 0):

- using urllib.request is a standard library for url processing (HTTP).
- using requests is a third-party but more convenient library for url
  processing (HTTP).
- using socket is a low-level network interface (TCP/IP).

Socket is lower level according to the OSI model, which means it can handle not only HTTP but also other application-level protocols.
At the same time, the code is more complex and there is more of it.

Yes! nginx server is not required at the development stage. You can just run gunicorn on a specific port and refer to it example: http://127.0.0.1:7000
in the browser

Comment: I understand urllib and socket are standard library and requests are external. one. It seems requests is easy-to-handle compared to urllib. I feel using socket is interesting becase the code shows each communication step.